# Invariance property of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable with $m(A)>0$. Does there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that the complement of

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A+x_n)$$

in $\mathbb{R}$ has measure $0$?

My guess is that there does not exists such a sequence as $m(A)=m(A+x_n)$ since measure is translation invariant. Also, are we assuming $m(A)$ is infinite or finite? Clearly, if $m(A)=\infty$ then the empty set works as an example.

Comment: Just drawing a picture, I think that a sequence with image $\lbrace z\mathrm{diam} A: z \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ works. Then $A+ x_n$ are disjoint a.e. .

Comment: @Meowdog am I misunderstanding your construction or does it not work with sets such as $(0,1/4)\cup (3/4,1)$ where the $\mathrm{diam}(A)=1$ but translations miss out on intervals?

Comment: Have you tried letting $A$ be a nowhere dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ with positive measure? I think the gaps between points (and the property of containing no intervals) will help

Comment: @varpi I see... yes should not work